# Delete all associated media when custom post type removed

Tags: custom-post-types, media-library

Basically I have so many images associated with custom post type that I need to be able to safely delete all related media on removal from trash.

Is there a safe way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your post to image association custom?

If not attachments should be automatically deleted by Wordpess.
If the connection is custom, Wordpress provides a [delete_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post) action that fires before and after a post is deleted, it will pass the ID of the post so you can use that to delete all custom content associated with it.